# How do you connect to database instances of different SQL versions?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In my system, I am required to have two versions of SQL Server (2008 and 2019). Please don't ask why.

Onto my issue: I installed 2008 some time back, and am able to connect to the DB instance fine.

However, I recently installed 2019, and am trying to connect to my DB instance, which doesn't seem to be working.

Here're the steps I've done so far:

1. I installed SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition (Under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server, I now see the "150" and "MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER" folders.
2. I opened SQL Server Configuration Manager, and see that the new instance is running (According to the Config Manager, `SQLEXPRESS` is the name of the old instance, and `MSSQLSERVER` is the name of the new one)
3. I opened CMD and executed `sqlcmd -L`, but only see the `SQLEXPRESS` instance listed.

How can I get my 2019 instance up and connectable?

Comment: You installed developer - did you start it? Did you configure it and add logins, users, and databases? Can you connect to it using SSMS? And apparently your new instance is the default instance.

Comment: It might be helpful to run and post the results of the "Installed SQL Server features Discovery report" in the SQL Server 2019 Installation Center.

Comment: `sqlcmd -L` depends on the SQL Browser Service having up-to-date information. Have you restarted the SQL Browser Service since installing SQL 2019?

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be working." mean?

Answer (score 1):

> MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER

So it looks like you installed a default instance of SQL Server 2019.  Good.

> How can I get my 2019 instance up and connectable?

Check that the MSSQLSERVER service is started, and look at

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
```

to see verify that instance started, and run

```
 sqlcmd -S localhost
```

to connect to the instance.